# Null Session in the django-restful framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-sessions

Django rest framework

I'm setting the session key once a user logins in

```
request.session['id'] = 1
```

Then when I try to access it in the class view like

```
id = request.session.get('id', 0)
```

It is `null [0]` if the end-point call is made from the browser but it returns `1` if end-point call is from postman...

I need your guidance...

Answer (score 0):

```
Session cookies are browser-specific - they are only sent back to the server if the request comes from the same browser that received the cookie in the first place.
Postman is not a browser - it is simply making raw HTTP requests. It will not send any cookies back, so of course you will not see session data.
This behavior is entirely expected and by design. Sessions are only persisted per-browser.
If you want to make API calls and authenticate them, you should use token authentication instead, which can be passed in the Authorization header of requests and is not tied to a browser session.
```